# Using native Android view in ReactNative: Constructor ReactImageView in class ReactImageView cannot be applied to given types

Tags: android, react-native, view, react-android

Attempting to create an Android view to use in **ReactNative** later on.

This is the code that I wrote following the [official tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-android.html), but I'm still getting some troubles compiling.

Here is the **error message** that I get:

```
Error:(15, 53) error: constructor ReactImageView in class ReactImageView cannot be applied to given types;
required: Context,AbstractDraweeControllerBuilder,GlobalImageLoadListener,Object
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Here instead is the **code**:

```
package com.androidbridge;

import com.facebook.react.uimanager.SimpleViewManager;
import com.facebook.react.views.image.ReactImageView;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext;
import com.facebook.drawee.backends.pipeline.Fresco;
import javax.annotation.Nullable;

public class ReactImageManager extends SimpleViewManager<ReactImageView> {

    public static final String REACT_CLASS = "RCTImageView";

    private Object mCallerContext;

    public ReactImageManager(Object mCallerContext) {
        this.mCallerContext = mCallerContext;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return REACT_CLASS;
    }

    @Override
    protected ReactImageView createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
        return new ReactImageView(reactContext, Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder(), mCallerContext);
   }
}
```

I am kind of lost as the code is derived from the official tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the signature of the class ReactImageView has changed since the tutorial was written, the constructor now also require you to pass an object of type GlobalImageLoadListener. It is [marked as nullable](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/803e993e6a8e68c62870e27ce4a45b485e244ec4/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/image/ReactImageManager.java#L50) as of the latest react-native version, so you can try just passing a null reference.

I just got started myself and find the tutorial somewhat lacking.